# How come my program can connect to a nonexistent website?

Tags: python, http, ironpython

I am new to python and network programming and I am having trouble with a simple program. I am basically opening a connection to a nonexistent website and somehow it seems that the connection succeeds. Moreover, I get a 200 return code which means the http server has responded that it exists and the connection is OK. Here's the relevant part of my code:

```
import httplib

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("Nonexistentsite.com", 80)
conn.request("GET","/")
r  = conn.getresponse()
print r.status, r.reason
conn.close()
```

And when I try `google.com` or any other existing website instead of `nonexistentsite.com`, I get 301 or 302 - `Moved permanently`.

Could you kindly clarify why this is happening, please? I am using visualStudio2010(IronPython) if that matters.

Comment: Weird, in regular Python I get the proper `socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`, maybe you encountered a bug?

Comment: Unless it's an ironpython implementation problem, may I suggest the problem is somewhere else in your code. Most likely incorrectly catching the exception that is thrown over here (on regular python) from `getresponse()` when the site doesn't exist. Or have you tested with *exactly* the code above? You say it's the relevant part which implies there are other parts.

Comment: @tjm I have posted all the code. As you can see I am not handling any exceptions. Is this the expected behavior though?

Comment: @Karen. Sorry, I really don't know, but I receive the error over here (the same one John Doe receives) P.S. Note, it throws in `request` not `getresponse` as I said above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You might be using an ISP that fakes DNS results in order to give you a <strike>spam page</strike> helpful search page instead of an error for nonexistant names.

What does a `ping Nonexistentsite.com` result in on the machine where you tested your Python code?

Comment: DNS somehow finds some IP for it [92.242.144.2], but ping times out.

Answer (score 0):

Running your code in Cygwin's Python, I get an error for `Nonexistentsite.com`, so I'm not sure if something weird is happening with IronPython.

Google.com is `Moved permanently` because Google has a system of redirects for their main page.  For example, if they detect you are in the UK, `google.com` will redirect you to `google.co.uk` (untested, I am in the US, but that is what I have read).   If I try your code with `stackoverflow.com` or another site that doesn't have something as complicated set up as Google, I get a `200 OK` response.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this except I used www.google.com instead. This came up with 302 Found. After a bit of googling I found out that 302 Found means that there is a redirection. This probably means that users are redirected to the right Google site for their reigon for example www.google.co.uk for UK. The 302 - Moved Permanently is probably the same thing but it just comes up different for IronPython.

edit -

It exists because Google is still running that server and is performing redirections.