# How to prevent 301 code from redirecting website?

Tags: python, http, ironpython, pycurl

I am trying to connect to websites with Python and get the HTTP status codes. As answers on [this other question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8027158/how-come-my-program-can-connect-to-a-nonexistent-website) suggest, the reason that HTTP status code for websites such as google.com are 301 or 302 (permanently moved) is that these servers are redirecting. However, I would like to be able to connect to them in such a manner that I get the natural 200 (OK) from them. Here's my current code:

```
import httplib

conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("google.com", 80)
conn.request("GET","/")
r  = conn.getresponse()
print r.status, r.reason
conn.close()
```

What do I need to alter/add to achieve this? I heard that `pycurl` library might help me with that, but googling hasn't brought any useful results so far. I am a novice in this field, so please excuse me if the question is trivial.

Comment: duplicate question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/301924/python-urllib-urllib2-httplib-confusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume what you want is for your code to follow the 301/302s to the end url which returns a 200?

If so you could try using `urllib`, or better still use `requests` which you can install with pip.

Both `urllib` and more reliably `requests` should follow 301's and 302's and give you the final page that returns a 200.

Info on the requests module can be found here:
http://pypi.python.org/pypi/requests/

Hope this helps.