# python urllib2 timeout

Tags: python, sockets, urllib2

Ok guys, i've search in google and here in stackoverflow for this answer and after a few hours did not see a correct answer of a working script to do this....

Here i paste 4 examples of supposed python working scripts to set a default timeout for a non-exist url with a timeout set with sockets and/or the timeout param.

No one works so the timeout is never triggered.

Any ideas?

First exmaple:

```
import urllib2

try:                
    header_s = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11"}

    req = urllib2.Request("http://www.nonexistantdomainurl.com/notexist.php",headers = header_s)


    print urllib2.urlopen(req, None, 5.0).read()

except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print "Url Error: %r" % e

except Exception,e:
  print "Fallo de tipo ",e

else: 
    print "all ok!"
```

Second example:

```
import urllib2

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.nonexistantdomainurl.com/notexist.php", None, 2.5)
except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print "Oops, timed out?"
```

Thrid example:

```
from urllib2 import Request, urlopen, URLError, HTTPError
import base64


req = Request('http://www.nonexistantdomainurl.com/notexist.php')

try:
    response = urlopen(req,timeout=5.0)   

except HTTPError, e:
    print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request.'
    print 'Error code: ', e.code
except URLError, e:
    print 'We failed to reach a server.'
    print 'Reason: ', e.reason
```

Fourth example:

```
import urllib2
import socket


socket.setdefaulttimeout(5)

try:
    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://www.faluquito.com/equipo.php",timeout=5.0).read()   


except urllib2.URLError, e:
    print "Url Error: %r" % e
```

Comment: Possible explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8028602/190597

Comment: thanks @unutbu but that's another situation not related to a timeout issue. There she want to know how is she becoming 200 when sending bad locations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import urllib2
>>> import time
>>> import contextlib
>>>
>>> def timeit():
...   s = time.time()
...   try:
...     yield
...   except urllib2.URLError:
...     pass
...   print 'took %.3f secs' % (time.time() - s)
...
>>> timeit = contextlib.contextmanager(timeit)
>>> with timeit():
...   r = urllib2.urlopen('http://loc:8080', None, 2)
...
took 2.002 secs
>>> with timeit():
...   r = urllib2.urlopen('http://loc:8080', None, 5)
...
took 5.003 secs
```

Comment: Nice approach but try with this command : r = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.faluquito.com/equipo.php',None,5) ... and see what happens. Also i tried your example in my terminal and it never reaches 2 or 5 seconds... it tooks 0.145sec and so....

Comment: @dyoser, do not forget to explicitly specify the protocol `http://`. I tried to connect to your `http://faluquito.com/equipo.php`. It constantly takes about 10 seconds, I think the problem is with the domain names resolving, connecting seems to be delegated to a blocking OS routine, and exits right after the control is on the Python's side. I may be wrong though.

Comment: that's because the editor did not show it :) but there it is (the http:// www i mean).. Yes ,that seems to be working like you say so the timeout is useless in some cases.

Answer (score 1):

If your machine has the unix program dig, you may be able to identify non-existent urls like this:

```
import logging
import subprocess
import shlex

logging.basicConfig(level = logging.DEBUG,
                    format = '%(asctime)s %(module)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s',
                    datefmt = '%M:%S')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

urls = ['http://1.2.3.4',
       "http://www.nonexistantdomainurl.com/notexist.php",
       "http://www.faluquito.com/equipo.php",
        'google.com']

nonexistent = ['63.251.179.13', '8.15.7.117']
for url in urls:
    logger.info('Trying {u}'.format(u=url))

    proc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(
        'dig +short +time=1 +retry=0 {u}'.format(u = url)),
                            stdout = subprocess.PIPE, stderr = subprocess.PIPE)
    out, err = proc.communicate()
    out = out.splitlines()
    logger.info(out)
    if any(addr in nonexistent for addr in out):
        logger.info('nonexistent\n')
    else:
        logger.info('success\n')
```

On my machine, this yields:

```
00:57 test INFO: Trying http://1.2.3.4
00:58 test INFO: ['63.251.179.13', '8.15.7.117']
00:58 test INFO: nonexistent

00:58 test INFO: Trying http://www.nonexistantdomainurl.com/notexist.php
00:58 test INFO: ['63.251.179.13', '8.15.7.117']
00:58 test INFO: nonexistent

00:58 test INFO: Trying http://www.faluquito.com/equipo.php
00:58 test INFO: ['63.251.179.13', '8.15.7.117']
00:58 test INFO: nonexistent

00:58 test INFO: Trying google.com
00:58 test INFO: ['72.14.204.113', '72.14.204.100', '72.14.204.138', '72.14.204.102', '72.14.204.101']
00:58 test INFO: success
```

Notice that dig returns `['63.251.179.13', '8.15.7.117']` for non-existent urls.

I believe my ISP is changing non-existent addresses to either 63.251.179.13, or 8.15.7.117. Your ISP may do something different. You may have to change `nonexistent` to something else in that case.